# Python AES decryption - Padding is incorrect

Tags: python, aes

I am fairly new to AES en/decrypting so bare with me.
Using the Crypto (Cryptodome) Library, I am trying to decrypt a message with a known key and a known iv as String.

```
from base64 import b64decode
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util import Padding

key = "some_key_as_string" #
key = base64.b64decode(key)
key = key.rjust(16, "0")

iv = "some_iv_as_string"
iv = b64decode(iv)

cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
ct = b'Test_ciphertext'
ct = ct.ljust(16, "0")

message = Padding.unpad(cipher.decrypt(ct), AES.block_size)
```

However this gives me an Error called 'Padding not correct' which I am not able to remove by myself.
The keysize should be 256 bit, not sure if I included this with the encoding.

Can you tell me what I am missing here?

Edit: I should add that rjust only worked for me when I encoded the "0".
So instead of

```
key = key.rjust(16, "0")
```

I used

```
r = str.encode("0")
key = key.rjust(16, r)
```

as well for the ct

Comment: Neither the `rjust()` nor the `ljust()` call should be necessary. Apart from that, the code should work. Probably your data is corrupted or you are using a wrong encoding. Post test data please.

Comment: When I leave out both rjust/ljust calls, I get an Error saying : 
"Data must be padded to 16 byte boundary in CBC mode" With data, does they mean the message I want to decode or either the key or the iv?
Edit : 
the message I use is a string looking like this: 'e/rmZ1EPUO/tNjHl02gFmilU4hJv465gIjEW8Q=='
the start and finish look like this, I deleted the middle part tho

Comment: The error message says that the ciphertext has an incorrect length. For a block cipher mode like CBC, the ciphertext must have a length that is an integer multiple of the block size, i.e. 16 bytes for AES.

Comment: Incomplete data is of no use. Post the length of the Base64 decoded data. But with regard to the error message, this length is probably not divisible by 16. Without concrete test data or the encryption code, we can only guess here.

Comment: If I counted correctly, my original message should have 2200 characters. Still no multiple of 16, wich I would need right?

Comment: It is not the number of characters that matters, but the number of bytes after decoding. The number of bytes must be divisible by 16.

Comment: and if i understoof it correctly, I convert the string into bytes, and since its the encrypted message, the message itself should have a length of 16*x . So maybe its an decoding issue. When I decode the string and print it out, the byte-variant is looking exactly the same

Comment: It can be an encoding problem or the data can be corrupt or the algorithm or the mode can be wrong etc. To answer this, the encryption code or at least test data is needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242031/discussion-between-ric-and-topaco).